# You have already authorized facebook, iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

Now I have an iOS Application that using facebook SDK to login using user facebook account, obviously you know that. And here is my code which i use to do this stuff.

```
-(void)loginButtonClicked
{
    FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"] fromViewController:self handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error)
     {
         if (error)
         {
             // Process error
         }
         else if (result.isCancelled)
         {
             // Handle cancellations
         }
         else
         {
             if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"])
             {
                 NSLog(@"result is:%@",result);
                 [self fetchUserInfo];
             }
         }
     }];
}

- (void)fetchUserInfo
{
    if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken])
    {
        NSLog(@"Token is available : %@",[[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]tokenString]);

        [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"id, name, link, email, birthday, bio, location, friends, hometown, friendlists"}]
         startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
             if (!error)
             {
                 NSLog(@"resultis:%@",result);
             }
             else
             {
                 NSLog(@"Error %@",error);
             }
         }];

    }
}
```

Problem is when user deleted app and they install then signin back again, the dialog of facebook login show "You have already authorized {ApplicationName}" and user must click OK to return my app.

All I want that they only need tab to login button then a loading circle show up and success.

Any idea to do that?

Comment: what the output you need

Comment: you dont want this `You have already authorized {ApplicationName}`  again if user press the login button

Comment: Yes I want this, How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Choice-1**

if you press the `Login` button, call this

**delete all granted permisson**

```
[[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me/permissions" parameters:nil 
HTTPMethod:@"DELETE"] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

 if (error)
     {
         // Process error
     }
     else if (result.isCancelled)
     {
         // Handle cancellations
     }
     else
     {
      // call your login action and create the new session
       [self loginButtonClicked];
     }

 }];
```

**Choice-2**

if you want to clear the current session use like

```
-(void)loginButtonClicked
{
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[login logOut];
[FBSDKAccessToken setCurrentAccessToken:nil];
// then continue the same process
```

**update**

if you want to bypass the connection

```
 -(void)loginButtonClicked
{
if FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken != nil
{
  // already logged in with the requested permissions 
}
else
{
  // start the login process
}
}
```

**Swift**

**delete all granted permisson**

```
  FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/permissions", parameters: nil,  HTTPMethod: "DELETE").startWithCompletionHandler({(connection:  FBSDKGraphRequestConnection, result: AnyObject, error: NSError) -> Void in
if error! {
    // Process error
}
else if result.isCancelled {
    // Handle cancellations
}
else {
    // call your login action and create the new session
    self.loginButtonClicked()
}

})
```

**Choice-2**

if you want to clear the current session use like

```
func loginButtonClicked() {
var login: FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
login.logOut()
FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken = nil

// then continue the same process

}
```

**update**

```
func loginButtonClicked() {
if FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken != nil {
    // already logged in with the requested permissions
}
else {
    // start the login process
}
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my bad english, I mean, I don't want clear session. I want when user have already authorized permission then some how we can skip that step and put user into app in straight way

Comment: Ok but when user delete app and they signin back, they still see this screen http://www.appcoda.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/t13_7_authorize.jpg I want they don't need to see this and automatic perform login directly, it's posible to do that?

Comment: @vietnguyen09- all answer is available in my answer, if your logout on that time  use choice 1 , choice 2 , it delete your all permission and session , if you press the login button it shows the login details bro