# Facebook authentication is giving 'You have already authorized' message

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook SDK's FBSDKLoginManager() to signup and login users into my app. Similar to many other questions posted on stackoverflow, I am running into the error message 'You have already authorized'. On a quick glance my question might seem duplicate, however I have researched all posted solutions to those questions and, as suggested on those solutions, ensured that following has been set correctly:

1) set the Configured for iOS SSO: to enabled (as suggested here: [facebook login give me already authorized this app without automatic returning to the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888582/facebook-login-give-me-already-authorized-this-app-without-automatic-returning-t))

2) connect AppDelegate class to the FBSDKApplicationDelegate object

3) Before initiating the FB login process, I am also checking if FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken is nil or has a value in it. (as suggested here: [You have already authorized facebook, iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37084850/you-have-already-authorized-facebook-ios))

Despite the above setups, I am still seeing the 'You have already authorized' message. Would appreciate further insights into solving the problem from someone else who has been into similar situation in past. Thanks.